# Проверка авторизованного пользователя

Tags: php, laravel

Как проверить авторизован ли пользователь по сессии?

`Auth::check()` и `Session::all()` - возвращают данные по текущей сессии. `Session::all()` так же возвращает поле `login_web_ ...` которое и говорит нам, что пользователь авторизован. Как добраться до него из текущей сессии, зная id другой сессии?

Comment: Что значит другая сессия? Для каждого пользователя создается только один файл сессии.

Comment: Другая значит не текущая для одного юзера. Да, файл один на юзера. как мне из одного авторизованного юзера узнать о состоянии другого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD.

Переделал через `Session::getHandler()` с методом `read($sessionId)`
http://php.net/manual/ru/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

```
public static function CheckBySessionId($sessionId = '') {
    $session = Session::getHandler()->read($sessionId);

    if (!$session) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach(unserialize($session) as $key => $val) {
        if (preg_match("/^login_web_[0-9a-z]+$/", $key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```